# How to delete unnecessary new line from string while reading file?

Tags: c++

I have created a simple file reader function which use std::map with std::tuple. The code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::tuple<int, double>> Map;

Map Readfile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream File(filename);
    if (!File.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "File '" << filename << "' does not exist.";
        exit(1);
    }
        
    Map data;
    std::string name;
    int a;
    double b;
    
    while (std::getline(File, name, '\t') >> a >> b)
    {
        data.insert({name, std::tuple<int, double>(a, b)});
    }
    
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    std::string file = "file_read_v3.txt";
    
    auto mt = Readfile(file);
    
    std::for_each(mt.begin(), mt.end(), [](std::pair<std::string,std::tuple<int, double>> it) {
        std::cout << it.first << "\t" << std::get<0>(it.second) << "\t" << std::get<1>(it.second) << std::endl;
    });
    
    return 0;
}
```

The contents of the text file I read:

```
Yvis    25  63.25
Wogger X Y  2   6.2
Bilbo   111 81.3
Mary    29  154.8
```

The data in the file is separated by tabs (`'\t'`). When I compile the source code, I discovered a rather strange thing on the command line: for some reason, there is a new line break after reading each line. I see this on the command line:

```
Bilbo   111     81.3

Mary    29      154.8

Wogger X Y      2       6.2
Yvis    25      63.25
```

What is the solution to this problem? And how to avoid not sorting the scanned data?

Comment: Read the full line with `std::getline` and tokenize that with a `std::stringstream`. No confusion about which delimiter is used for each then. When you tell getline to read to the next tab it does what you ask, including reading the newline.

Comment: The newline is at the beginning of of the name on the next line, as it is the next character in the input stream after reading the value stored in `b`.

Comment: I tend to use regular expressions for the line parsing. Not sure which approach wins performance wise but having capture groups in the regex provides easy access and error checking.

Comment: Thank you @RetiredNinja! I have modified the while loop and I have used the `std::stringstream`.